# Backup from S3 to S3

Tags: backup, amazon-s3

I'd like to backup multiple S3 buckets into another S3 buckets. It seems like most backup tools only support S3 as a destination, but not as a source e.g. restic. The backup should support pruning, deduplication, not having to download the entire bucket to disk.

Also, I'm not using AWS, but a S3-compatible storage from another cloud provider.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the aws cli sync command.

[documentation](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)

I don't think you can backup multiple buckets with one command, so you would need to use it multiple times for example:

```
aws s3 sync s3://sourcebucket1 s3://targetbucket
aws s3 sync s3://sourcebucket2 s3://targetbucket
...
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution won't work for me because any accidental deletes will be propagated to backup. And if I were to sync it to a new folder, lots of redundant storage would be used.